# Python: memory leak with memory_profiler

Tags: python, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I want to use `memory_profiler` package to analyze memory usage.

However, I've some confusions:

### Example 1

```py
# test1.py
from memory_profiler import profile

class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


list = []

@profile
def func():
    for i in range(100000):
        list.append(Object())


func()
```

### Results 1

##### First test

```
mprof: Sampling memory every 0.1s
running new process
running as a Python program...
Filename: test1.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    10     43.9 MiB     43.9 MiB           1   @profile
    11                                         def func():
    12     50.1 MiB      0.0 MiB      100001       for i in range(100000):
    13     50.1 MiB      6.2 MiB      100000           l.append(Object())
```

[image]

##### Second test

```
mprof: Sampling memory every 0.1s
running new process
running as a Python program...
Filename: test1.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    10     44.2 MiB     44.2 MiB           1   @profile
    11                                         def func():
    12     50.3 MiB  -2867.4 MiB      100001       for i in range(100000):
    13     50.3 MiB  -2861.3 MiB      100000           l.append(Object())
```

[image]

##### Question 1

About `test1.py`:

1. The result of memory usage is **different** some time.
2. Are there have memory leak in this example? I think python have **garbage collection** mechanism, so `list` should be `None` which will not cause memory leak. However, the result of `mprof plot` show usage increase.

---

### Example 2

```py
# test2.py
from memory_profiler import profile

class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


@profile
def func():
    global list
    list = []
    for i in range(100000):
        list.append(Object())


func()
```

### Results 2

```
mprof: Sampling memory every 0.1s
running new process
running as a Python program...
Filename: test2.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     7     44.2 MiB     44.2 MiB           1   @profile
     8                                         def func():
     9                                             global l
    10     44.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       l = []
    11     50.3 MiB  -2905.3 MiB      100001       for i in range(100000):
    12     50.3 MiB  -2899.2 MiB      100000           l.append(Object())
```

[image]

##### Question 2

About `test2.py`:

1. I think this example will cause a memory leak. The reason is that after the function ends, `list` as a **global variable** still holds a reference to the list, and the objects in the list are not released, resulting in a memory leak.
2. But why the result of `Increment` was `-2899.2 MiB` which seem there are not happend memory leak.

Comment: " I think python have garbage collection mechanism, so list should be None which will not cause memory leak." I don't understand you. The list should never "be None" (not really sure what you mean by that). Both your examples are appending to a list that maintains a reference in the global scope. So you would expect the memory to increase in both examples. In that sense, both have "memory leaks" (although, I would not call these memory leaks)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
example 1 the list is declared globally, so the garbage collector should automatically reclaim the memory when the program ends. Therefore, there shouldn't be a memory increase. 
In example 2, the list is declared within the function. Therefore, I think the garbage collector may not be able to reclaim the memory automatically when the program ends, leading to a memory increase. Am I misunderstanding how the mechanics work?

Comment: Yes you are misunderstanding. Both lists are referenced globally (python *doesn't have declarations*). Memory will always be reclaimed when the process ends on pretty much most modern operating systems, and that has nothing to do with Python. But regardless, there is no difference in either examples, since they both create a global reference to the list. When the program stops, both have a global reference to the list you created

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, If that's the case, then I cannot understand why there a result of `-2867.4 MB` for increment? Shouldn't this result indicate that the memory has been properly released? Or is it the operating system handling the deallocation? And how can memory be correctly released in the example1、2?

Comment: I've tried to use `l=None` after `func()` in example1, but the result of `memory_profiler` still same.

Comment: Python is a *memory managed language*. It exposes no methods to *release memory*. Objects are kept alive on a privately managed heap in CPython, the most common implementation which you probably using, and are only garbage collected when they are no longer reachable. CPython uses reference counting as its main memory management strategy (the only one relevant in your code, since your code doesn't create reference cycles, which are handled by an auxiliary garbage collector). In both of your programs, your list stays referenced until the completion of the program.

Comment: You are profiling the execution of the function, so `list = None` won't affect anything. I don't use `memory_profiler`, and the values for `increment` don't make sense to me, but just googling around, I find that the `increment` column often has confusing results: e.g. [look at this PR](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/pull/202). During the execution of your function, the list will still be referenced, and indeed, the actual memory usage is what you would expect from that code. The graph shows a steady increase, which is *again* what you would expect.

Comment: So again, there are no memory leaks in your either of your programs. Both create a list that is maintained until the end of the program, and the `memory_profiler` is showing a resulting memory usage (ignoring whatever "increment" is showing you here) that is perfectly in line with what you would expect.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks so much, I forgot that "profiling the execution of the function". Everything can explain correctly if ignore "increment". your save my day!